# Library for developing XMPP server in C++ or Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, xmpp, qxmpp

I have to develop a simple [XMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) server that will be included in a commercial project. I guess there isn't any server available that can be purchased with a royalty-free-license and that enables me to do the configuration and user management and the authentication from my own code.

The languages I can use are [Delphi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi) and [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B).
I've already looked at the libraries listed at *xmpp.org*, but most of them seem to be client-only libraries or (as e.g. QXmpp) requires Qt which I don't have any experience of and I consider it to be a pure GUI framework.

What would be a library I should take a closer look at? Does it make sense to familiarize myself with Qt for this purpose (writing an XMPP server; no GUI)?

Or is it better to just catch a stream parser (suggestions?) and code it myself?

---

The only library I could find for Delphi, IP*Works is a pure client library. I am evaluating QXmpp now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Delphi part of my question: I didn't find a library I think that is suitable for building a server.

For the C++ part, I think this post [Non GPL C/C++ XMPP client library for embedded Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522606/non-gpl-c-c-xmpp-client-library-for-embedded-linux) (though it is for embedded and client) is answering my questions:

> Because Qt provides XML parser and signal/slot framework. XMPP requires XML parser, and signal/slot framework makes your life easier. If you try implementing entire XMPP with all extensions in OOP fashion, you'll need something similar to Qt.

and

> Advice: when it comes to C++, there aren't many good xmpp libraries available.

So I think, QXmpp seems to be a good solution.

For other people searchig for this topic:

IMHO the documentation (especially for the server part) is a bit poor. The server example distributed with the qxmpp library is (of course) very basic: It is transporting chat messages. Distributing presence information, roster, subscription handling has to be implemented by you via extensions (inheriting QXmppServerExtension overwriting at least virtual function handleStanza). Don't parse the presence or iq stanzas in your own code. For the more common stanzas the libarary has classes implemented QXmppPresence, QXmppRosterIq etc.) that also can be used in your extension.